# Because one line of unrelated code, the speed difference so much

Tags: c++, linux

**Why use the precompiler to add a line of code, the speed change is so great?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


#ifndef LINUX
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

const int SIX_MILLION = 6000000;
const int ONE_MILLION = 1000000;

unsigned long long randint()
{
    return (unsigned long long)(rand() & 0xFFFF) << 16 | (unsigned long long)(rand() & 0xFFFF);
}

#ifdef LINUX
int time_substract(struct timeval *result, struct timeval *begin, struct timeval *end)
{
    if (begin->tv_sec > end->tv_sec)    return -1;
    if ((begin->tv_sec == end->tv_sec) && (begin->tv_usec > end->tv_usec))    return -2;
    result->tv_sec = (end->tv_sec - begin->tv_sec);
    result->tv_usec = (end->tv_usec - begin->tv_usec);

    if (result->tv_usec < 0)
    {
        result->tv_sec--;
        result->tv_usec += ONE_MILLION;
    }
    return 0;
}
#endif

double time_it(function<void()> func, int times = 3)
{
#ifndef LINUX
    LARGE_INTEGER lpStart[1], lpEnd[1], lpFreq[1];
    vector<double> result(times);
    ::QueryPerformanceFrequency(lpFreq);
    for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
        ::QueryPerformanceCounter(lpStart);
        func();
        ::QueryPerformanceCounter(lpEnd);
        result[i] = (lpEnd[0].QuadPart - lpStart[0].QuadPart)  * ONE_MILLION  / double(lpFreq[0].QuadPart);
    }
    nth_element(result.begin(), result.begin() + (times / 2), result.end());
    return result[times / 2];
#else
    struct timeval start, stop, diff;
    vector<double> result(times);
    memset(&start, 0, sizeof(struct timeval));
    memset(&stop, 0, sizeof(struct timeval));
    memset(&diff, 0, sizeof(struct timeval));
    for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
        gettimeofday(&start, 0);
        func();
        gettimeofday(&stop, 0);
        time_substract(&diff, &start, &stop);
        result[i] = (diff.tv_sec * 1000000  + double(diff.tv_usec));
    }
    nth_element(result.begin(), result.begin() + (times / 2), result.end());
    return result[times / 2];
#endif
}

size_t prepare_data(set<unsigned long long> &data, unsigned int size, bool strict = false) {
    data.clear();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data.insert(strict ? i * 3 : randint());
    }
    return data.size();
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    set<unsigned long long> a;
    set<unsigned long long> b;
    vector<unsigned long long> result(SIX_MILLION);
    double res;
#ifdef TEST
    prepare_data(a, SIX_MILLION);
#endif
    prepare_data(a, SIX_MILLION / 2, true);
    prepare_data(b, SIX_MILLION / 2);
    res = time_it([&a, &b, &result]() {
        auto iter = set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), result.begin());
        result.resize(iter - result.begin());
    });
    cout << "duration: " << res << " microseconds,set a size: " <<
        a.size() << " set b size: " << b.size() << " set result size: " << result.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

ubuntu@host:~/test_intersection$ g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -DLINUX  main1.cpp -o main1
ubuntu@host:~/test_intersection$ ./main1
duration: **62080** microseconds,set a size: 2998917 set b size: 3000000 set result size: 2087
ubuntu@host:~/test_intersection$ g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -DLINUX **-DTEST** main1.cpp -o main1
ubuntu@host:~/test_intersection$ ./main1
duration: **362546** microseconds,set a size: 2998985 set b size: 3000000 set result size: 2149

Comment: To be fair, you should add the ability to use the same random seed across tests.  And you should reseed the generator just before the very last call to `prepare_data`.  Also, I would use a different name than `TEST` just in case there's some other obscure code being activated by that.  Use your name instead, or something.  If the tests still show significantly different, perhaps you have stressed out the memory with all those early allocations, and your slow test is suffering from more fragmentation.

Comment: You probably should take weeks to read a good C programming book (and about its [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)). With the second compilation, you are calling `prepare_data(a, SIX_MILLION);`

Comment: I believe the point is that `prepare_data` clears the set every time it's called, and this initial setup happens outside of the timed test run.  So I should ask if anyone else read the code.

Comment: Duration does not include the time of prepare_data.

Comment: FYI, I ran this on my Mac Pro (clang-703.0.31) and had sane timings (56011 _vs._ 58897).  It's possible, if you're running this on a virtual host somewhere, that your big test triggered a system policy that throttled your application due to the large burst in processing.  Rather than using wall clock time, perhaps measure CPU time.

Comment: Thank you! This difference only exists in the linux system it 's not exist on windows too.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so.  I have done an experiment and written up an answer.  It would help verify my results if you could provide some figures on how much memory your Ubuntu system has, and whether it is a 32-bit or 64-bit kernel.

Comment: The behaviour certanly looks abnormal. It happens on Linux when using glibc malloc and diasppears with -ltcmalloc, so this could be a glibc malloc bug/misfeature.

Comment: What fascinates me about this question is that it immediately attracted a whole bunch of downvotes, even though it is a clear question and shows research effort.  I think people here are too quick to judge, especially with new site visitors.  People must take a step back and actually read a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same result as you on my Ubuntu droplet hosted at DigitalOcean.  It has fairly limited RAM.  Prior to running the test, it had about 220MB free (output of `/usr/bin/free -tm`):

```
# free -tm
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            493         153         220          14         119         298
Swap:             0           0           0
Total:          493         153         220
```

When I run the slow test, I can watch the available memory get completely soaked up.

```
# free -tm
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            493         383          10          14          99          69
Swap:             0           0           0
Total:          493         383          10
```

Just in case the `clear()` method kept all that memory reserved internally, I tried instead:

```
data = std::move( std::set<unsigned long long>() );
```

But this made little difference.

So one of my original suspicions is that you have fragmented your memory by exhausting it with a data structure like `std::set`, which performs lots of allocations to build a tree and then frees them in an unspecified order (due to the arrangement of nodes in the tree).

To simulate this, I replaced the `TEST` section with code that performed a lot of allocations and then released them in a different order (by stepping over the list using a prime number stride).

```
#ifdef TEST
    //prepare_data(a, SIX_MILLION);
    {
        std::vector<void*> mem(SIX_MILLION);
        for( auto & val : mem ) val = malloc(24);
        for( int i=0, p=0, step=499739; i < SIX_MILLION; i++) {
            p = (p + step ) % SIX_MILLION;
            free(mem[p]);
        }
    }
#endif
```

Allocations of 24 bytes were sufficient to stress the memory allocator on my system, leading to **similar results to those you have described**.  I found that if I free the values in a more predictable order (i.e. walking through from first to last), this did not have the same effect on performance.

So I would say the final explanation for this is that you are a victim of memory fragmentation.  You filled up your memory with lots of small allocations, and then freed them in a random order.  You then built new data sets, which suffered from poor cache locality because the allocation system was stretched.  This had a measurably severe impact on performance when it came to calculate an expensive intersection of these two data sets.

Comment: This brings up more questions than it solves. Why should there be any fragmentation in the end of the allocate/free cycle? We're freeing *all* the allocated memory. Doesn't malloc merge adjacent free blocks?

Comment: That's a good point @n.m.  Normally fragmentation occurs when allocating additional data and freeing the stuff in between.  But it's a lot of work to completely untangle and merge free blocks that happen in random order (and seemingly even my test that punched holes in regular intervals).  You surely can't expect malloc to hand out memory blocks in sequential order after this, even if all that memory is free.  My suspicion is that under the hood, free blocks are chained together in a different order, depending on when they become free.

Comment: A malloc implementation that doesn't merge adjacent free blocks (neighbouring addresses, not necessarily next to each other in the list of blocks) is questionable to say the least. Why should Linux malloc exhibit this behaviour and Windows or Mac OS X mallocs not?

Comment: The tests were not equivalent enough to conclude anything.  I ran this on a Mac with 16GB of RAM.  That's unfair to compare with a virtual host with 500MB, unless I adjust it to eat all my memory.  I'm not going to do that.  I don't _know_ that this is fragmentation, but it exhibits that kind of behaviour.  It does certainly seem to be something related to the memory system -- whether that's the kernel's handling of virtual memory, a malloc implementation or whatever.  What do you suppose might be going on?

Comment: This looks like a major glibc malloc bug to me. I have tried this with -ltcmalloc and the behaviour disappears.

Comment: I would be interested to run some address locality heuristic over a second batch of malloc calls and see if they are all over the place.  That would be fun to try.  But I am at work right now and have duties.